# rvm: command not found MAC OX

Tags: macos, command, rvm

Really, I don't know what happened. Excuse me if this question is so NOOB, but I can't find the solution for this problem.

> -bash: rvm: command not found

I tried this

> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --version latest

but still nothing I need to see the ruby version for use the simplecov because it not works with older version from 1.9

Answer (score 265, accepted):

It might because the terminal not having rvm shell configuration loaded.

Try following from your terminal:

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

then

```
$ type rvm | head -n 1
```

If the output is:

```
rvm is a function
```

You may need to add "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to your ~/.bash_profile file

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me too. What is the reason for this? Did I miss a step when installing rvm?

Comment: @Bruno I came to this page too, then realised it actually says in the install message: To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: doesn't work. First command returns "no such file or directory" other ones - rvm not found

Comment: @peterpengnz it worked on my mac even without the second command i.e i didn't need to write it down in the bash_profile

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov I had the same problem, I guess you are running with sudo, if you don't it will work

Comment: Shoudn't we specify here that the last step should be adding `~/.bash_profile file` to the Path in `~/.bash_profile` (make the instructions a bit more explicit) ?

Comment: This is not a complete answer, see mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914964/1223975

Comment: Hi, I try you solution by typing ```source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm``` in terminal, but I get ```/Users/mine/.rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
/Users/mine/.rvm/scripts/rvm:29: command not found: ps
``` is there a way to solve it?

Comment: How to add "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to your ~/.bash_profile file?

Answer (score 56):

you need to read all the texts that are displayed when you install RVM:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mpapis i was trying to install rvm for past couple of hours but cound not figure out why rvm command not found was coming. The first line did the trick. Thanks again

Comment: No go. LOTS of error messages. This reminds me of the bad old days of Linux.

Comment: And how do you do this? "You may need to add "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to your ~/.bash_profile file".

Answer (score 53):

after you run `sudo curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

**you need to close the terminal ,then open again!**

Comment: The `close` was important. Thanks.. I restarted and it worked

Comment: I didn't close, I just ran `source /Users/[my_account_name]/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Comment: Silly me... closed & reopened terminal. thanks, it works!

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @mpapis, Do this first

`$ rm -rf ~/.rvm`

`$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Then, as suggested by @peterpengnz, do this and you should be fine with RVM cmd issues

`$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: Can you provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 5):

`source /etc/profile` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

For a long-term solution, you should add this to your `~/.profile` file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to simply load rvm into a single terminal, use

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

supposedly this call is more cross-platform:

```
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 2):

Close and restart terminal after installing RVM — gets me EVERY TIME.

Answer (score 1):

To start using RVM, you'll need to enter `source /Users/yourusername/.rvm/scripts/rvm` into your terminal (of course, insert your real username in place of `yourusername`).

Comment: you can use `~` as a replacement for `/Users/yourusername`
as in: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Answer (score 1):

If you received `gpg` error like this:

```
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Then run the following commands:

```bash
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm list
rvm use 3.2.2 --install
```

Answer (score 0):

Close and reopen your terminal. Sometimes, the changes made during the installation of rvm are not immediately picked up by your terminal, so reopening it should resolve the problem.