# ruby 2.0 rails gem install error "cannot load such file -- openssl"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using **osx 10.8.2** installed **ruby 2.0** and....
 got this when trying to run **"sudo gem install rails"**

```
$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I had ruby 1.9.x and rails 3.2.x working alright before

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You have to install OpenSSL first and recompile ruby again:

RVM:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-gcc=gcc-4.7 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Comment: I suggest you add `ruby_configure_flags=--with-openssl-dir="$rvm_path/usr"` to `~/.rvm/user/db` so that if you re-install Ruby again to add another package you don't forget to include OpenSSL.

Comment: How about on Windows??

Comment: I am also having this problem on windows. Any help for us?

Comment: @ValeryKvon I was compiling ruby from source. Then I executed gem install bundler. I got this error : 

`ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @user1429980 for windows don't worry about the installation process. You can straight away download rails installer and install .exe: http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: This worked for me _without_ the `--with-gcc` flag, FWIW.

Comment: `-bash: rvm: command not found`, see: [rvm: command not found MAC OX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11776021/394969)

Comment: if suggested command fails with error about missing gcc in PATH, use `--with-gcc` without certain version helps:
`rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-gcc --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr`

Comment: This helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 40):

If you're using RVM please follow:

```
$ brew install automake
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm requirements run
$ rvm reinstall all --force
$ gem install rails
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This was not a bad answer! reinstall --all --force takes a LONG time though if you got alot of rubies... be prepared...

Comment: This is a much better, more complete answer than the accepted one. do this.

Answer (score 11):

I had very bad time with this ERROR.
Finally i done with it. There is only Once solution either you are with RVM or without RVM.

**Make sure you have installed OpenSSL first BEFORE installing ruby.**

**RVM**

1. Uninstall rvm

   rvm implode

or

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

Don’t forget to remove the script calls in your .bashrc and/or .bash_profile (or whatever shell you’re using).
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev build-essential openssl libssl-dev libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libyaml-dev curl git-core python-software-properties libpq-dev nodejs

Then install RVM, post ruby.

OR

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-gcc=gcc-4.7 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

**WITHOUT RVM**

First you should find where Ruby is:

```
whereis ruby
```

will list all the places where it exists on your system, then you can remove all them explicitly. Or you can use something like this:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
```

THEN

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev build-essential openssl libssl-dev libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libyaml-dev curl git-core python-software-properties libpq-dev nodejs

apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev
cd /tmp
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p247/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 7):

I fix this error for ruby 2.1.2 as follow.

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. This work in Centos 9 Stream and ruby 2.6.0

Answer (score 4):

On OSX, with rbenv and homebrew, the following worked for me:

```
brew install openssl
CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) rbenv install whatever-ruby-version
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me which is similar to some of the other answers already posted.

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall all --force
```

Answer (score 1):

When installing ruby 2.0, it is possible that rubygems 2.0 installation did not complete ok, because of openssl.
Make sure you provide a valid path to the openssl config file; you could:

```
find . -type f -name "openssl.cnf"
```

path is usually $HOME/.rvm/usr or $HOME/.rvm/usr/ssl

Then

```
[sudo] rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-openssl-dir=[openssl.cnf path] --verify-downloads 1
```

Make sure rubygems installation complete successfully.
Might be a better way to fix that path without reinstalling, but this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check out this page on the rvm site:  https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/

Running

`rvm requirements run`

gave me:

`Missing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, apple-gcc42, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite`

after `brew install autoconf automake ...`

I was able to `rvm reinstall 2.0.0` without openssl errors

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same OS version. I use rvm and followed the steps in this command:

```
$ rvm requirements
```

Following those instructions, I ran:

```
$ brew update
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew install bash curl git
$ brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 libtool pkg-config openssl readline libyaml sqlite libxml2 libxslt libksba
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier, tried all of the snippets about and none of them worked out.  After looking around for a bit the following worked for me:

```
$ rvm remove 2.0.0 # get rid of unsuccessful installation
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.0.0
```

What does `rvm get head --autolibs=3` do exactly?  I'm guess it automatically downloads dependencies, but I was hoping for a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same openssl error on Fedora when trying to use `gem install <package>`. It seems you need to install additional packages with yum/dnf

```
sudo dnf install rubygems rubygem-bundler ruby-devel mariadb-devel
```

After running the above command, `gem install <package>` should now work.

Answer (score 0):

just went through the same problem. Takes a bit time but, upgrading openssl with

```
brew upgrade openssl@1.1
```

worked for me. Version might be different in the future, type brew install openssl to see which version you can upgrade to. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have libssl**1.1**, your problem may be that these older versions of ruby (2.4 is the cutoff) are only compatible with libssl1.0.

For debian/ubuntu, please ensure that `apt-get install libssl1.0-dev` succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ruby-install`, it will take the same openssl argument as rvm:

```
ruby-install ruby-2.0.0-p247 -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```