# updating to the latest version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

using mac10.7.5  ran rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247

Downloading https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2 failed.
Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
rm: /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_path: Permission denied

any ideas ?

Comment: Write the exact procedure and detailed error messages, otherwise no one can help you by guessing.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

Comment: got an error There is no checksum for 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.1.11.tgz' or 'rubygems-2.1.11.tgz', it's not possible to validate it.
This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. You may want to
update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

There has been an error while trying to fetch rubygems. 
Halting the installation.

Comment: WINNER!! - now trying to install rails 4 , no rails installed so typed $ sudo gem install rails get error ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129355/ruby-2-0-rails-gem-install-error-cannot-load-such-file-openssl

Comment: thanks for the prompt help ,its asking me to update to the latest version of xcode so should be ok