# Using Rubygems on Debian: Cannot install gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian, zlib

I seem unable to install any gems. When I try something like `sudo gem install rails` or `sudo gem install rdiscount` I get the following errors:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
        undefined method `invoke_with_build_args` for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone please help me figure out the cause of this problem?

Comment: Did you install all required dependencies? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129355/ruby-2-0-rails-gem-install-error-cannot-load-such-file-openssl

Comment: have my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this you have not installed all required libs for. the [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) works, either install it for the [debian](/questions/tagged/debian), or use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) and install ruby version you need with it from sources.