# Error installing gems: cannot load such file -- zlib

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install bundler gem on Mac OS Yosmite

```
~/code/hello gem install bundler
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I've done the following:

- Install zlib through homebrew
- Upgrade Rubygems
- Reinstall RVM and Ruby 2.2.2
- Switched to Rbenv and Ruby 2.2.2

This is really doing my head in. Ruby 2.2.1 works fine but 2.2.2 causes this issue whenever I try to install a gem.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/zlib
rvm reinstall 2.2.2 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8
```

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into it.

Comment: This works very well. Thankyou @stephenmurdoch! I would add a comment though to check if zlib is already installed with `brew info zlib`. For me, the directory was the same, but I think it would be good to have that information to help prevent a complete copy and paste and get the user thinking a bit :)

Answer (score 4):

Try `rvm pkg install zlib`
(from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129355/ruby-2-0-rails-gem-install-error-cannot-load-such-file-openssl))

RVM pkg docs: https://rvm.io/packages

---

It also looks like RVM has a more up to date way of managing packages called `autolibs`. Check `rvm autolibs show`, which I hope will be `default(enabled)` since you just installed. If it's not, `rvm autolibs enable`, or you can even tell it to use Homebrew instead of its own manager with `rvm autolibs homebrew`.

RVM autolibs docs: https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added a working fix but your advice got me part of the way there