# SASS installing error on MAC OS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macos, sass, installation

Trying to install sass but can't.

Getting the following 2 errors .

> sudo gem install sass .
>
> ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError) .    cannot load such file
>   -- zlib .
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) . 
>       undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

**FYI:**
Ruby version - ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16] . 
xCode already installed .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233255/error-installing-gems-cannot-load-such-file-zlib

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the command line developer tools first 
xcode-select --install
Use this command in your terminal and install the xcode and then run SASS.
Worked for me!

Comment: I did it, but my problem was ruby version conflict. now fixed. thanks for the reply.