# bundler always not found when switched ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

i am using rvm and my default ruby is the latest Ruby , but i want to swith ruby version to 2.3.8
and after i run `rvm use ruby2.3.8` and i want to run `bundle install` it said bundle not found, and then i tried to install bundle `gem install bundler` 
then error i got is:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

i already re install rvm and read some question about that error on this SO to get openssll  ( my openssl already installed by brew ) such [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129355/ruby-2-0-rails-gem-install-error-cannot-load-such-file-openssl)

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Did you install 2.3.8 recently or is it possible that you installed 2.3.8 some time ago and in the meantime updated openssl? Afaik openssl needs to be installed before installing a Ruby version.

Comment: install recenly and i already downgrade bundle to version 3.0.6 also