# Error during creation of new React Native app

Tags: react-native

```
npx react-native@latest init test
```

I used the above command to create a react native project named test. The result is as below:

```
                                                          
               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               
                                                          

                  Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error /Users/subratadas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/subratadas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/subratadas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

The above error means Ruby Gems is not installed. So i tried below command:

```
gem install bundler
```

The error occured as below:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Then i followed accepted answer from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129355/ruby-2-0-rails-gem-install-error-cannot-load-such-file-openssl)

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

The output is as below:

```
Beware, 'rvm pkg ...' is deprecated, read about the new autolibs feature: 'rvm help autolibs'.

Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Fetching openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz to /Users/subratadas/.rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /Users/subratadas/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1i.....
Configuring openssl in /Users/subratadas/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1i.......................
Compiling openssl in /Users/subratadas/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1i.......................................
Installing openssl to /Users/subratadas/.rvm/usr....................................................-
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/subratadas/.rvm/log/1700706059/openssl_make.install.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates.......
```

Then i tried:

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

The output is:

```
ruby-2.7.5 - #removing src/ruby-2.7.5 - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.7.5 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/14.1/arm64/ruby-2.7.5.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Updating certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/subratadas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.7.5 - #downloading ruby-2.7.5, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.7.5 - #extracting ruby-2.7.5 to /Users/subratadas/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5 - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #installing - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/subratadas/.rvm/log/1700706254_ruby-2.7.5/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

Then to know which openssl has been installed on my system, i tried:

```
which openssl
```

the result:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/openssl
```

Then i tried:

```
rvm reinstall all --force -C --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/bin/openssl
```

But this time also same result as the previous.

what to do?

SUMMARY: able to run react native app on android but not on ios.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew unlink openssl@3
brew link openssl@1.1 --force
rvm pkg install openssl
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
rvm reinstall all --force
sudo gem install cocoapods
gem update --system
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**